# Is it possible to expose an indexer from a Xamarin Java bindings library?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm creating a Xamarin Java bindings library. In my Java code, one of my classes looks like this:

```
public class ColoringList {
    public long get(int index) { ... }

    public void set(int index, long element) { ... }
}
```

I wish to expose this from the bindings library in C#:

```
public class ColoringList
{
    public long this[int index] { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to modify Xamarin's `Metadata.xml` file so this gets exposed instead of

```
public long Get(int index);
public void Set(int index, long element);
```

? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other people who run into this problem, the solution is to 1) make the methods internal in `Metadata.xml`:

```
<attr
    path="/api/package[@name='com.bluejay.repository']/class[@name='ColoringList']/method[@name='get']"
    name="visibility">internal</attr>
<attr
    path="/api/package[@name='com.bluejay.repository']/class[@name='ColoringList']/method[@name='set']"
    name="visibility">internal</attr>
```

Then, create a file in the bindings library called `YourClass.Manual.cs` and add the following code to wrap the methods:

```
public partial class YourClass
{
    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => Get(index);
        set => Set(index, value);
    }
}
```